# Why does flow make me check for an undefined value that is already defined?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

In the following code flow throws an error if I don't check for the existence of `response`. But the `const response` definition should guarantee that response is available. Why does flow not accept omitting the check for the existence of `response`?

```js
/* @flow */

// ... import dependencies

export function* loadDepartments(): Generator<*, *, *> {
  try {
    const response = yield call(getJson, endpoints.departments);
    if (response && typeof response.data !== 'undefined') {
      yield put(actions.loadingDepartmentsSucceeded(response.data));
    }
  } catch (errors) {
    yield put(actions.loadingDepartmentsFailed(errors));
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand that it makes me check for `response.data` by the way, there's no guarantee that that property exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event if you used `const`, the value of `response` can be `undefined`, depending on what your `call` function yields. A variable defined with `const` can indeed contain the value `undefined`.

In case `response` is undefined, then the check

```
if (typeof response.data !== 'undefined') {
```

would raise a TypeError because you can't read property "data" of `undefined`.